# How to initialize IDictionary in constructor?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

In TagBuilder and other classes I can write something like:

```
var tr = new TagBuilder("HeaderStyle"){InnerHtml = html, [IDictionary Attributes]}
```

but I don't know how to pass the IDictionary parameter.

How can I do that *on the fly*? Without creating a Dictionary variable.

TagBuilder is an example, there are other classes that accept a parameter `IDictionary`as well. The question is about the generic case.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following blog post has a helper method that can create Dictionary objects from anonymous types.

http://weblogs.asp.net/rosherove/archive/2008/03/11/turn-anonymous-types-into-idictionary-of-values.aspx

```
void CreateADictionaryFromAnonymousType() 
   { 
       var dictionary = MakeDictionary(new {Name="Roy",Country="Israel"}); 
       Console.WriteLine(dictionary["Name"]); 
   }

private IDictionary MakeDictionary(object withProperties) 
   { 
       IDictionary dic = new Dictionary<string, object>(); 
       var properties = 
           System.ComponentModel.TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(withProperties); 
       foreach (PropertyDescriptor property in properties) 
       { 
           dic.Add(property.Name,property.GetValue(withProperties)); 
       } 
       return dic; 
   }
```

Comment: It doesn't work for TagBuilder because, as you correctly point out, the setter is private.

Answer (score 39):

Another way to create Dictionaries from Anonymous types:

```
new Dictionary<int, StudentName>()
{
    { 111, new StudentName {FirstName="Sachin", LastName="Karnik", ID=211}},
    { 112, new StudentName {FirstName="Dina", LastName="Salimzianova", ID=317}},
    { 113, new StudentName {FirstName="Andy", LastName="Ruth", ID=198}}
};
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb531208.aspx

Answer (score 0):

If you're referring to the Attributes property, the setter is private, so you can't set it in an object initializer.

After you've initialized the TagBuilder, you should be able to add individual attributes with `tr.Attributes.Add(key,value)`.